# Keycloak, PKCE and external IDP

Tags: authorization, keycloak, openid-connect, idp, pkce

I have a requirement where I need to federate to an IDP. I have never had issues in the past and in this instance, I have an issue because the third party/external IDP has PKCE enabled and enforced.

Is there a way to federate to an IDP which has PKCE enabled. Basically in other words, I should be able to forward/send code_challenge and code_challenge_method to the external IDP. I can enable PKCE on my IDP without any issues and forward the same headers to the external IDP if required but I dont see a way to do it. I tried to configure "Forwarded Query Parameters" field on the Identity Provder Configuration as well but to no avail.

However I came across this ticket https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-9809 where is it said that this is not supported since its only supported for public clients - so is it still the case?

In addition to this, if this is not supported, what is the recommended way to get around this? I mean I could ask the external IDP folks to change their configurations but I'd like to know the recommended way before proposing a way out.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Got the same issue. Did you solve it ?

Comment: nope. however, I posted a question on the keycloak thread and got a link to this ticket - https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7381 - according to this - the issue is sorted out in keycloak 13.0.0

Answer (score 1):

The issue is apparently resolved on ticket - https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7381

According to this ticket - the issue is resolved in version 13.0.0. Unfortunately, I have moved away from this project - so if someone can confirm that this works with 13.0.0 - I can mark this as the answer and close off the post.